# Send alert to multiple channels in MS Teams

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I want to send alerts to multiple channels.

Below is my configuration for reference:

```yaml
receivers:
      - name: default-receiver
        # slack_configs:
        #  - channel: '@you'
        #    send_resolved: true
      - name: prometheus-msteams
        webhook_configs:
        - url: "http://prometheus-msteams.monitoring:2000/alertmanager"
          send_resolved: true
      - name: prometheus-msteams_1
        webhook_configs:
        - url: "http://prometheus-msteams.monitoring:2000/alertmanager_1"
          send_resolved: true    

    route:
      group_by: ['alertname']
      group_interval: 5m
      repeat_interval: 15m
      group_wait: 30s
      receiver: 'prometheus-msteams'
      routes:
        - receiver: prometheus-msteams
        - receiver: prometheus-msteams_1
```

Here it is sending an alert to only one channel which written first in routes. In this case sending alert to `prometheus-msteams` channel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prometheus alertmanager send notifications to multiple slack channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62672730/prometheus-alertmanager-send-notifications-to-multiple-slack-channel)

Answer (score 2):

By default alertmanager stops on first matched route. You should say him to continue.

```
    route:
      group_by: ['alertname']
      group_interval: 5m
      repeat_interval: 15m
      group_wait: 30s
      receiver: 'prometheus-msteams'
      routes:
        - receiver: prometheus-msteams
          continue: true                 # <---- continue matching
        - receiver: prometheus-msteams_1
```

https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/

```
# Whether an alert should continue matching subsequent sibling nodes.
[ continue: <boolean> | default = false ]
```