# How to send alerts to multiple receivers

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I want to add multiple receivers in Alertmanager: both slack and mail. But only one is working at a time.

Here is my current attempt of configuration:

```yaml
  config:
    global:
      resolve_timeout: 5m
    route:
      group_by: ['job']
      group_wait: 30s
      group_interval: 5m
      repeat_interval: 12h
      receiver: 'null'
      routes:
      - receiver: 'email'
        matchers:
        - severity =~ 'critical|warning'
      - receiver: 'slack-notifications'
        matchers:
          - alertname =~ "InfoInhibitor|Watchdog" 
    receivers:
    - name: 'null'
    - name: 'email'
      email_configs:
      - to: 'xxx'
        from: xxx
        auth_username: xxx
        auth_password: xxx
        auth_identity: xxx
    - name: 'slack-notifications'
      slack_configs:
      - send_resolved: true
        api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx'  
    templates:
    - '/etc/alertmanager/config/*.tmpl'
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prometheus alertmanager send notifications to multiple slack channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62672730/prometheus-alertmanager-send-notifications-to-multiple-slack-channel)

Comment: As advised in linked question you need to use `continue: true` config option.

Comment: I tried adding continue: true but still it is not working.

Comment: Check this tool: https://www.prometheus.io/webtools/alerting/routing-tree-editor/. If I add `continue: true` it shows both receiver active. Please double check your attempt.

Comment: Hi @markalex ..pls find snap from route-tree-editor and pls suggest

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to show me. As I said before, if you add `continue: true` and check alert with labels matching both selectors it shows that both receivers are being used: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKGtW.png